# Shortcut to open URL with copied text in clipboard

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, url

I need to open a URL address which has a key at the end which opens different items. Something like a id system.
ex : www.example.com/userid=1234

I want to have a shortcut in PC in a way that I can highlight any text/number and with certain shortcut key combination open above url with 1234(as in example above) replaced with highlighted text.
ex : I highlight on text 8765 in some notepad and click shortcut key that copies this and replace in URL and open the same for me i.e opens www.example.com/userid=8765

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using AHK or NirCmd.

- Download [NirCmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) and copy the executable to the Windows directory.
- Create a desktop shortcut with the following target or command-line:

  ```
  nircmd.exe exec max "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "http://www.example.com/userid="~$clipboard$
  ```
- Assign a hotkey for the shortcut (e.g., `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `W`)

I've used Chrome as the example. Replace the browser executable path in the command-line accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Windows, a shortcut is <kbd>Win+R</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Opens any URL that the system recognizes.

Comment: The link should contain `http://` or `https://` otherwise...